# Android region specific translations loaded in other regions

Tags: android, kotlin, translation

My app by default is in Spanish so string.xml texts are Spanish. Later i have other languages:

- For English i have strings-en.xml
- For Portuguese of Portugal i have strings-pt-rPT.xml
- For Spanish (Colombia) i have strings-es-rCO.xml

The problem is that i have my device in Spanish (Spain) language and is loading the translations of strings-es-rCO why? If that strings are for a region specific, i would pick strings.xml values

I have tested in english and Portuguese of Portugal and seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this: [Challenges in resolving language resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support#preN)

Basically, before Android 7, if you selected a specific language locale that the app didn't support, it would try removing the end of the locale (getting less specific) to try and find a match:

```
es_RCO -> es -> default (e.g. English)
```

What that means is if it can't find the basic `es` locale, it gives up completely, even if you have say `es_MX` providing an available Spanish translation.

They changed that with Android 7 - now if it can't find `es`, it *will* look for children of that locale. Meaning if you have an `es_MX` translation, it'll default to that, since it's at least the same language the user selected, just not the correct region.

So because you've selected `es` for your language, and there's no base Spanish translation, it has to go looking in the regional locales instead. That's why (ideally) you'd put your Spanish translation in `es`, and any regional variations in the strings can be added to things like `es_RCO` where necessary.

Comment: Hi:
Ok I understand, my problem is that my default is Spanish strings.xml is in spanish, so even i don't have strings-es.xml my strings.xml is like strings-es.xml

Maybe the problem is that is thinking my default language is english but in fact is spanish, but i don't find a place where i can say my strings.xml is Spanish.

Comment: @Miguel sorry, I have no idea - I've never had to change the default from `en-US`, and it seems impossible to find info on this. You could try specifying the languages here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support#specify-the-languages-your-app-supports and put `"es"` first, but I feel like that won't work. Worth a try though! Some other stuff here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#app-language-settings including an Android 13 feature that lets you define a default locale, and more gradle settings, if it helps with testing